# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'

Tags: python, csv

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader')

when I run the code below but I can't see why?

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as f:
    q = csv.reader(f)
```

Comment: You have a file in your local directory called `csv.py`; rename it.

Comment: yeah i deleted it and it seems to work fine now, thanks !

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You imported a *different* `csv` module, not the one in the standard library. Perhaps you named your own script `csv.py` for example.

Find out what is imported instead by printing out the filename of the module:

```
import csv
print(csv.__file__)
```

If that's not in the standard library, rename or delete this file, and remove the `csv.pyc` file if there is one next to it.

Comment: yeah i had one called csv.py in the same folder so i deleted it and it worked, thanks for your help !

Comment: Having a variable named "csv" can cause this issue as well.

Comment: @JoshCorreia: but then the error would tell you a different type of object doesn't have that attribute, here the error in for a `'module' object`.