# Importing csv file produces an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv

with open('SalesJan2009.csv') as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')
    print(readcsv)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ANIKET/PRACTICE PROGRAMS/python projects/csv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import csv
  File "D:\ANIKET\PRACTICE PROGRAMS\python projects\csv.py", line 3, in <module>
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader'
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing your own file (csv.py). You need to rename your `csv.py` file and try again. This is duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341363/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-reader)

Answer (score 3):

Your own script is called "csv.py" so it's trying to import iteself.
Since you do not have the attribute "reader" inside your own script, it's not found.

Try renaming the script you are running and you should be fine.

Comment: i m getting this result:"<_csv.reader object at 0x000002219B5B8798>"

Comment: That is the representation of the reader object you created. Have a look at the docs for more info on how to use that object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader