# Cannot read ".parquet" files in Azure Jupyter Notebook (Python 2 and 3)

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently trying to open parquet files using Azure Jupyter Notebooks. I have tried both Python kernels (2 and 3).
After the installation of *pyarrow* I can import the module only if the Python kernel is 2 (not working with Python 3)

Here is what I've done so far (for clarity, I am not mentioning all my various attempts, such as using *conda* instead of *pip*, as it also failed):

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install -I Cython==0.28.5
!pip install pyarrow

import pandas  
import pyarrow
import pyarrow.parquet

#so far, so good

filePath_parquet = "foo.parquet"
table_parquet_raw = pandas.read_parquet(filePath_parquet, engine='pyarrow')
```

This works well if I'm doing that off-line (using Spyder, Python v.3.7.0). But it fails using an Azure Notebook.

```
 AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-2739da3f2d20> in <module>()
      6 
      7 #table_parquet_raw = pd.read_parquet(filePath_parquet, engine='pyarrow')
----> 8 table_parquet_raw = pandas.read_parquet(filePath_parquet, engine='pyarrow')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_parquet'
```

Any idea please?

Thank you in advance !

EDIT:

Thank you very much for your reply Peter Pan !
I have typed these  statements, here is what I got:

1.

```
    print(pandas.__dict__)
```

=> read_parquet does not appear

2.

```
    print(pandas.__file__)
```

=> I get:

```
    /home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py
```

3. import sys; print(sys.path) => I get:

   ```
   ['', '/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python34.zip',
   '/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4',
   '/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
   '/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
   '/home/nbuser/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
   '/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
   '/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py3.4.egg',
   '/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.4.egg',
   '/home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
   '/home/nbuser/.ipython']
   ```

Do you have any idea please ?

EDIT 2:

Dear @PeterPan, I have typed both `!conda update conda` and  `!conda update pandas` : when checking the Pandas version (`pandas.__version__`), it is still `0.19.2`.

I have also tried with `!conda update pandas -y -f`, it returns:
`Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/nbuser/anaconda3_23:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
pandas: 0.19.2-np111py34_1`
```

When typing:
`!pip install --upgrade pandas`

I get:

`Requirement already up-to-date: pandas in /home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz>=2011k in /home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.9.0 in /home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil>=2 in /home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5 in /home/nbuser/anaconda3_23/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)`

Finally, when typing:

`!pip install --upgrade pandas==0.24.0`

I get:

`Collecting pandas==0.24.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==0.24.0 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0rc1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0rc2, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0rc1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0rc1, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0)
No matching distribution found for pandas==0.24.0`

Therefore, my guess is that the problem comes from the way the packages are managed in Azure. Updating a package (here Pandas), should lead to an update to the latest version available, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue on my Azure Jupyter Notebook, but failed. There was no any issue for me without doing your two steps `!pip install --upgrade pip` & `!pip install -I Cython==0.28.5` which I think not matter.

Please run some codes below to check your import package `pandas` whether be correct.

1. Run `print(pandas.__dict__)` to check whether has the description of `read_parquet` function in the output.
2. Run `print(pandas.__file__)` to check whether you imported a different `pandas` package.
3. Run `import sys; print(sys.path)` to check the order of paths whether there is a same named file or directory under these paths.

If there is a same file or directory named `pandas`, you just need to rename it and restart your `ipynb` to re-run. It's a common issue which you can refer to these SO threads [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341363/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-reader) and [Importing installed package from script raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or "ImportError: cannot import name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250353/importing-installed-package-from-script-raises-attributeerror-module-has-no-at).

In Other cases, please update your post for more details to let me know.

---

The latest `pandas` version should be `0.23.4`, not `0.24.0`.

I tried to find out the earliest version of `pandas` which support the `read_parquet` feature via search the function name `read_parquet` in the documents of different version from `0.19.2` to `0.23.3`. Then, I found `pandas` supports `read_parquet` feature after the version `0.21.1`, as below.

[image]

The new features shown in the [`What's New`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/whatsnew.html) of version `0.21.1`
[image]

According to your `EDIT 2` description, it seems that you are using Python 3.4 in Azure Jupyter Notebook. Not all `pandas` versions support Python 3.4 version.

The versions [`0.21.1`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/install.html#python-version-support) & [`0.22.0`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/install.html#python-version-support) offically support Python 2.7,3.5, and 3.6, as below.
[image]

And the [PyPI page for `pandas`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) also requires the Python version as below.

[image]

So you can try to install the `pandas` versions `0.21.1` & `0.22.0` in the current notebook of Python 3.4. if failed, please create a new notebook in Python `2.7` or `>=3.5` to install `pandas` version `>= 0.21.1` to use the function `read_parquet`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @PeterPan  ! I habve edited my question. Could you please take a look? -Best regards

Comment: @Menas Try to print your pandas version via `pandas.__version__`. In my local machine, I installed `pandas` via `conda install pandas` in my miniconda environ, and the version is `0.23.4` which has the function `read_parquet`. You can try to update your conda or pandas via `!conda update <conda or pandas>` in iPython.

Comment: Dear @PeterPan, when you have time, could you have a look to my  latest update please? (Or anyone else who would know how to solve this issue :-)

Comment: @Menas Please see my update answer. After I researched for your information, you can try to install the pandas versions `0.21.1` & `0.22.0` in the current notebook of Python `3.4`. if failed, please create a new notebook in Python `2.7` or `>=3.5` to install pandas version `>= 0.21.1` to use the function read_parquet.

Comment: Dear @PeterPan, Thank you very much, the problem is now solved! I have updated the Kernel to 2 (Python 2.7) and updated Pandas to 0.22.0. After installing PyArrow, everything works like a charm!